# ConcurrentModificationException: .add() vs .addAll()

Tags: java, foreach, concurrentmodification

Why does the following occur? Shouldn't both work?

```
List<String> items = data;
for( String id : items ) {
    List<String> otherItems = otherData;        

    // 1.   addAll()
    //Causes ConcurrentModificationException
    items.addAll(otherItems);

    // 2.   .add()
    //Doesn't cause exceptions
    for( String otherId : otherItems ) {
        items.add(otherId);
    }
}
```

Is it because `add()` adds to the collection Items, but `addAll()` creates a new collection thus modifying Items to be a different instance of List?

**Edit**
`items` and `otherItems` are of concrete type `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: What concrete type is `Items`?

Comment: Because you have an iterator open on items and items doesn't support concurrent modification. Why you're allowed a single add is the real question. Either way, what you're doing here probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither operation is proper, since it modifies the collection while iterating it.

Examining [the implementation of ArrayList](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) shows that calling either `add` or `addAll` should successfully throw the ConcurrentModificationException on the next loop iteration. The fact that it isn't doing that for `add` means that either there is an obscure bug in the ArrayList class for the particular version of Java you have; or (more likely) `otherItems` is empty, so in the second case, you aren't actually calling `add` at all.

I'm sure `otherItems` must be empty, because if adding to the `Items` list "worked" in the way you want, then it would grow every time around the loop, causing it to loop indefinitely until dying with an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: You're right, otherItems was never being populated. It does fail if there is data in it, good catch!

Comment: @FreakyDan - which means the 'otherItems' would never have caused the CME either. Your code in your question is messed up. `addAll()` of an empty collection would not cause a CME.

Comment: @FreakyDan - actually, you may have found a bug in Java... hmmm. I am editing my answer.

Comment: @rolfl `addAll` of an empty collection does cause the CME. See the ArrayList code: `addAll` unconditionally calls `ensureCapacityInternal`, which unconditionally calls `ensureExplicitCapacity`, which unconditionally does `modCount++`.

Comment: I see that side effect now. That is a bug (in ArrayList). Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The for loop you have here

```
for( String id : Items ) {
```

is logically the same as:

```
for(Iterator<String> it = Items.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String id = it.next();

    ....
}
```

Now, if you modify the list an iterator iterates over, in the middle of iterating, you get the ConcurrentModificationException. From the [Javadoc for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So, the `addAll()` is modifying `Items`, and causing the iterator to fail.

Your only solution is to either:

1. don't do the addAll()
2. change to the loop with the iterator, and do:

   ```
   for (String other : otherItems) {
       it.add(other);
   }
   ```

   In other words, do the add via the iterator, and avoid the ConcurrentModification....

Now, about why `add()` works, and `addAll()` does not? I believe you are probably just seeing something like the add version when there are no other items in the iterator, or the values being added are emtpry, Perhaps a bug in the implementation of Items. It *should* be throwing a CME, and the fact that it is not throwing one, means there is a bug, not in your code, but in the collection.

They should both ***fail!***

**BUT**: You have subsequently found that the `addAll()` was adding an empty collection. An empty addAll() should not be causeing a CME... and, as @Boann points out, this is a bug in the implementation of ArrayList.

I have put together the following test to prove things out:

```
private static List<String> buildData() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"));
}

public static void testThings(List<String> data, List<String> addall, List<String> add) {
    System.out.printf("Using %s addAll %s and add %s%n", data, addall, add);

    try {
        for (String s : data) {
            if (addall != null) {
                data.addAll(addall);
            }
            if (add != null) {
                for (String a : add) {
                    data.add(a);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("OK: " + data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fail: " + e.getClass() + " -> " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] hw = {"Hello", "World"};

    testThings(buildData(), Arrays.asList(hw), null);
    testThings(buildData(), null, Arrays.asList(hw));
    testThings(new ArrayList<>(), Arrays.asList(hw), null);
    testThings(new ArrayList<>(), null, Arrays.asList(hw));
    testThings(buildData(), new ArrayList<>(), null);
    testThings(buildData(), null, new ArrayList<>());
    testThings(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), null);
    testThings(new ArrayList<>(), null, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

This produces the results:

```
Using [Hello, World] addAll [Hello, World] and add null
Fail: class java.util.ConcurrentModificationException -> null
Using [Hello, World] addAll null and add [Hello, World]
Fail: class java.util.ConcurrentModificationException -> null
Using [] addAll [Hello, World] and add null
OK: []
Using [] addAll null and add [Hello, World]
OK: []
Using [Hello, World] addAll [] and add null
Fail: class java.util.ConcurrentModificationException -> null
Using [Hello, World] addAll null and add []
OK: [Hello, World]
Using [] addAll [] and add null
OK: []
Using [] addAll null and add []
OK: []
```

Note the two lines:

```
Using [Hello, World] addAll [] and add null
Fail: class java.util.ConcurrentModificationException -> null
Using [Hello, World] addAll null and add []
OK: [Hello, World]
```

Adding an empty addAll causes a CME, yet that does not structurally modify the list. This is a bug in ArrayList.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought it was intentional that you could add to the end. I always viewed it as you can add to a chain, but you can't rearrange it. So in my inexperienced mind both should have worked.

Comment: I like this "Now, if you modify the list an iterator iterates over, in the middle of iterating, you get the ConcurrentModificationException." do you have any resource for that so I can read more?

Comment: @KickButtowski - The [JavaDoc for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): *The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.*

Comment: The specification is loose as to whether the CME should be thrown on the `nasNext()`, `next()` or both calls. Java libraries only throw on `next()` and not `hasNext()`, which some people consider to be a bug... as that is not 'fail fast'.

Comment: Thank you for linking that, my assumption is that ArrayList.add() works similarly to 'iterator's own [add method]' while .addAll() doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rolfl -> in both cases CME should be thrown...

Most probable answer:

addAll() is a first invocation, it throws Exception, and second piece of code is simply never reached -> you have forgotten to comment first part out and therefore think that add()-part is exception-free code  ;)